# PostgreSQL - Insert where not exists in another table / Reverse Foreign Key?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, subquery, sql-insert

I have two tables: `Records` and `Notifications` in a PostgreSQL database

The flow of logic is that I am going to be receiving many messages, which will be stored into the `Notifications` table. Every once in a while I take all the notifications grouped by a common identifier, then store one row into the `Records` table with that Identifier as it's primary key.

The thing is, later on, I may still receive notifications with the same identifier, but I want to ignore them if I have already created a record for it.

So my question is - Is there a good way to conditionally insert into `notifications` only if the identifier DOES NOT appear in the `Records` table? I'm thinking a "Reverse foreign key" where it will fail to insert if a column does appear in another table.

I know this SQL won't work but I'm trying to get something like this to happen:

```
INSERT INTO notifications (id, notification, timestamp) 
values (:id, :notification, now()) 
WHERE records DOES NOT HAVE :id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can phrase this with an `insert ... select` statement:

```
INSERT INTO notifications (id, notification, timestamp) 
SELECT s.*, now()
FROM (VALUES (:id, :notification)) AS s(id, notification)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM records r WHERE r.id = s.id)
```